# Namespaced routes not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I'm building an international website, therefore I managed to have URLs looking like `/{language}/{other_stuff}` thank to some manipulation in `RouteServiceProvider`

```
/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
public function map(Router $router, Request $request)
{

    $locale = $request->segment(1);
    $this->app->setLocale($locale);

    /**
     * Internationalization routing system
     */
    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace, 'prefix' => $locale], function($router) use ($locale) {

        if ($locale == 'en') require app_path('Http/routes_en.php');
        elseif ($locale == 'el') require app_path('Http/routes_el.php');

    });

}
```

Works like a charm. Every language will have his own route file, it's a choice.

Let's say we go to `/en/` and you're an admin, I created another namespace within `Http/route_en.php` to focus on the admin section :

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function() {

  Route::controller('', 'DashboardController');

  Route::controller('brands', 'BrandsController');
  Route::controller('contents', 'ContentsController');
  Route::controller('downloads', 'DownloadsController');
  Route::controller('news', 'NewsController');
  Route::controller('products', 'ProductsController');
  Route::controller('settings', 'SettingsController');
  Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');

});
```

So now I should access easily sections such as `/en/admin/brands` but it fails. I generate all my links dynamically thanks to the HTML class

```
{!! HTML::linkAction('Admin\BrandsController@getIndex', 'Brands') !!}
```

The generation works fine when I go to `/en/admin` which means `Admin\BrandsController@getIndex` is detected by this package, but when you click on it

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

I tested some stuff and when I just simply set the route outside `group()` it works fine.

```
Route::controller('admin/brands', 'Admin\BrandsController');
```

**What am I missing here ? Shouldn't the HTML class and the routing system agree with each others ? Is there any mistake I made ? Maybe there's an issue ?**

**EDIT : I opened [an issue for this problem on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8404)**

Comment: In your routes_en.php in the ```Route::group``` namespace try to replace 'Admin' to 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin'

Comment: `Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController does not exist` sadly it won't work this way either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So nobody tried to help me.

After a few days, an issue and many tests I understood the problem by myself : you have to put the `DashboardController` route at the end otherwise the routing system will take it first and ignore the other ones.

```
  /**
   * Admin
   */
  Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'is.admin'], function() {

    Route::controller('news', 'NewsController');
    Route::controller('brands', 'BrandsController');
    Route::controller('products', 'ProductsController');
    Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
    Route::controller('downloads', 'DownloadsController');
    Route::controller('settings', 'SettingsController');
    Route::controller('contents', 'ContentsController');

    Route::controller('', 'DashboardController');

  });
```

**NOTE : Everything will seem alright in the route listing, and even in the HTML/Form packages, but it's not.**

I let it here for anybody that would have similar problems.